# Node Async not executing the db function

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I am sending a post request from a form but async.waterfall() doesn't execute the mongoose's User.find() function to fetch users from the database and as a result the post request's status in the network inspector is pending as res.send() is not being called.

```
exports.createUser = function(req,res){
  var email1 = req.body.mail.toString();
  var password = req.body.password.toString();
  async.waterfall([


    function(callback) {

      // verify user in the db
      User.find({email:email1},function(err,data){
        if (err){
          res.send(404);
          return callback(err);
        }

        // user is found
        if (data.length != 0){
          res.send(404);
          return callback(new Error("User Found"));
        }

        callback();
      });
    },

    // generate salt password
    function(callback) {
      bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR,function(err,salt){
        if (err) return  callback(err);

        bcrypt.hash(password,salt,function(err,hash){
          if (err) return callback(err);
          return callback(null,hash);
        });
      });
    },

    //generate random string
    function(hash,callback){
      crypto.randomBytes(48,function(err,buf){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        var randomString   = buf.toString('hex');
        return callback(null,hash,randomString);
      });
    },

    // save them in the mongoDb using mongoose
    function(hash,randomString,callback){
      var userModel = new User;
      userModel.email = email1;
      userModel.password = hash;
      userModel.verificationId = randomString;
      userModel.save();

      callback(null,'done');
    }
  ],function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      res.send(404);
    } else{
      console.log("done");
      res.send("200");
    }
  });
}
```

Here is my app.js file using express

```
  // render the registration page
app.get('/users/create',register.renderUserPage);


app.post('/users/create',function(req,res){
  register.createUser(req,res);

});
```

Here is the Db.js file which connects to mongoDb using mongoose

```
  console.log("connection succeeded");

  var UserSchema = new Schema ({
  email: {type:String ,require : true ,index : {unique : true}}  ,
  password:{ type : String ,required: true}  ,
  verificationId:{type:String, required:true,index:true}
 });

 UserSchema.plugin(ttl,{ttl:90000000});


 module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

Comment: How do you know User.find() isn't being executed? Do you get a 404?

Comment: No i am not getting a 404 and also i tried to put console.log() messages there

Comment: So what output do you get?

Comment: No output post status in the network inspector is pending indefinitely

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with your database connection or how you're invoking Mongoose?

Comment: @shaunak1111 which HTTP error code are you getting ?

Comment: no the problem isn't with the db.I can connect to the mongodb and enter data when i manually pass res.end in the app.post() method

Comment: @Bulkan i am getting POST status pending.The server is waiting for the request to be parsed....

Comment: @shaunak1111 Not sure if this will help but I don't think you can only call `res.send` twice. In the callback for `User.find` if `data.length != 0` you call `res.send(404)` then `return callback(new Error(..))` then in `async.waterfall`'s callback you are calling `res.send` again. Also where is `userModel` defined ?

Comment: @Bulkan i have edited the code the usermodel is defind in the last callback function in the async.waterfall.I have tried and removed res.send() from the User.find() callback function  but still the same result

Comment: This might be really obvious, but you are making sure to actually connect to the database before you try to query it, right?